# Unwanted space above <body>, and no background-color.

Tags: html, css

Pretty noob question I'm sure. I ran into this problem when attempting to change the background color in a more complex webpage, so I started from scratch and still can't figure it out. [Here's the simplified page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmN42.png)

My goal is to set the background color of the site, but doing so with body had no effect, even when I had it filled with content. So I tried setting the  background color and instead ran into a whole new problem. The header is not at the top of the site, since there's an unwanted space above the body element itself. I've tried setting everything to margin 0 and padding 0 to no effect. Here is my code:

```css
html {
 background-color: green;
}

.body {
 
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

}

#logo {
 font-size: 2rem;
 border-right: 1px solid grey;
 color: green;
}

header {
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="description" content="blah">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  
  <header>
   
   <p id="logo">Path</p>
  
  </header>

  <section class="hero">
    
  </section>

  <section class="content">
    <p>hi</p>

  </section>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your CSS, `.body` should be `body`. If you use `.body`, that refers to a class, so you would need to use `<body class="body">` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried "body" instead of ".body"?

Comment: Oops. Still had no effect in getting rid of the top space though.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#logo {
margin-top: 0px ;
}

body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If this worked for you, then please upvote and mark that as correct answer so that community can get benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try add This in your CSS:

```
html,body,header,section,p{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
```

it Works, No unwanted space.

here the fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/osrrwrqn/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```